# Print Server Redundancy in VMware ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, failovercluster, windows-server-2019, print-server, fault-tolerance

I'm having a challenge figuring out the best way to get the highest possible uptime on my 2 print servers.
The best solution would be if one of the servers function as my primary print server, and the other would function as secondary, and as soon as the primary server would go offline for whatever reason, the secondary server could continue where the primary server left (Take over the printjobs etc.)

But any possible solution to my problem is appreciated!

This is my setup:

Running VMs on ESXi 6.7

Print servers run on Windows Server 2019

I will either run the 2 printservers on the same host, or if nessesary, run it on 2 hosts.

I have looked into NLB, Failover Cluster and VMware Fault Tolerance, but so far with no success.
Any help?

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Running 2 guests inside the same host defeats the purpose of redundancy.

Make a guest server on a separate host on a separate physical server.

Configure the print servers as primary and secondary.

Since you already have the primary, follow the guide [here](https://www.papercut.com/support/resources/manuals/ng-mf/common/topics/secondary-win-config-win.html) to make the secondary one.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there no way of doing it without the use of 3rd party software?

Comment: You can use Windows Clustering.